# Why iTerm2 show unicode characters in isolation?

Tags: iterm2, iterm

iTerm2 shows unicode characters in isolation, for example:

[image: iterm2]

As you can see in the above picture, it perfectly display the unicode characters separately. Whats the problem?

Comment: enable Unicode version 9 in the profile that you are using (text tab)

Comment: enabling this option doesn't solve the problem. This is a right-to-left language, is it relate to the problem? Each character is represent perfectly but in isolation from left to right.